# Firefox 4 news button

Tags: firefox

on upgrading to firefox 4 i seem to have lost the news dropdown from the toolbar.  How do i get it back

Answer (score 0):

Click on the **firefox *orange* button** > **options** > **bookmarks toolbar** select it, 
and you will have you bookmarks toolbar back with the rss feed dropdown of bbc news